# problema en entorno de pyqt6 y librerias que leen archivos xlsx

Tags: python, vscode, openpyxl, pyqt6, xlsx

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación que lea archivos de Excel y donde pueda visualizarlos en un dashborad creado con pyqt6.

Pero el problema esta en cuando intento importar las librerías como `xlsxwriter` o `Reader` o cualquier otra que lea archivos así y no me las importa al entorno virtual diciendo que no están instaladas pero abro otro proyecto de Python y si me importa las librerías.

Quiza sea un problema de configuracion u otra cosa, pero si me pueden ayudar por favor.

aqui el codigo que estoy usando para esto

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, 

QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QComboBox, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QBrush
from xlsxwriter import Workbook


class ExcelEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Excel Data Editor")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        filter_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.filter_column_label = QLabel("Filter by Column:")
        self.filter_column_combo = QComboBox()
        self.filter_column_combo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.apply_filter)
        self.filter_value_label = QLabel("Filter Value:")
        self.filter_value_input = QLineEdit()
        self.filter_button = QPushButton("Apply Filter")
        self.filter_button.clicked.connect(self.apply_filter)

        filter_layout.addWidget(self.filter_column_label)
        filter_layout.addWidget(self.filter_column_combo)
        filter_layout.addWidget(self.filter_value_label)
        filter_layout.addWidget(self.filter_value_input)
        filter_layout.addWidget(self.filter_button)

        layout.addLayout(filter_layout)

        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.load_data()

        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def load_data(self):
        workbook = Workbook("data.xlsx")
        sheet = workbook.active

        self.table_widget.setRowCount(sheet.max_row)
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(sheet.max_column)

        for col_index, col_letter in enumerate(sheet.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_row=1)):
            self.filter_column_combo.addItem(col_letter[0])

        for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            row_index = sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True).index(row)
            for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(cell_value))
                self.table_widget.setItem(row_index, col_index, item)
```

Comment: Para darle formato correcto al código, pon triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tal código. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.